# ASP: Switching between two ScriptManagers. Or how to remove script reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**General idea**

My general idea is to have mobile and desktop version of my site. Users can switch versions with buttons on the bottom of the page. I'm using ASP themes, so that I can easily switch themes depending on the required version of the site.

**The problem**

Switching themes is great, but since I've got `JavaScript` files already included in my project in the following `ScriptManager` in my master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jQueryMobileBehaviour.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Master.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" />
        </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

When the user switch to desktop version there are problems caused by `jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js` and `jQueryMobileBehaviour.js`. Is there a way to use two ScriptManagers (some sort of themes but for js files)?

**What I've tried without success**

My first approach was to remove the mobile `JavaScript` files from the `ScriptManager` and then include them manually in the click event of the button that switches to mobile version like that `sm.Scripts.Add`.

The second approach was to remove programmatically the mobile `JavaScript` files like that `sm.Scripts.Remove`.

```
    protected void CommandBtn_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Desktop":
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["theme"].Value = "Desktop";
                //sm.Scripts.Remove(new ScriptReference("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"));
                break;
            case "Mobile":
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["theme"].Value = "Mobile";                    
                //sm.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"));
                //Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
    }
```

Both approaches didn't work.

**To sum up the questions**

- Is there something wrong in my code - assuming that the paths should be alright?
- Is there a better approach, which will allow me to switch `JavaScript` files, like is done with the themes?

Comment: Maybe if you add two `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">` with two different setup and two different ids, and you swap them (one visible, one hidden) base on your them.

Comment: @Aristos I cannot add two ScriptManagers on one page. I'm currently looking for a workaround, but if you know how to add multiple ScriptManagers, please tell me.

Comment: @Aristos Thanks for your help I managed to solve my problem. I've added my solution below.

Comment: I am glad that I help you that way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution. I've tried adding two `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">` and make them `sm.Visible = true/false` depending on the version of the site as @Aristos suggested. However I could not use two `ScriptManager`s on the same page and also there is no property Visible of the `ScriptManager`.

So here is what I've done.

Firstly since I'll need to switch between two sets of scripts I've made two separate `ScriptManagerProxy` (because I could not have two `ScriptManager`s).

For the Desktop version:

```
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" ID="smDesktop">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Modernizr.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Modernizr_full.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Master.js" />
        </Scripts>    
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

and for the Mobile version:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" ID="smMobile">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jQueryMobileBehaviour.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Modernizr.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Modernizr_full.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Master.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

**IMPORTANT PART STARTS HERE**

Then I put them in two separate user controls, which I **registered** to the master page:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/ScriptManagerDesktop.ascx" TagName="smDesktop" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/ScriptManagerMobile.ascx"TagName="smMobile" TagPrefix="uc" %>
```

Then in the master page body I've inserted a ContentPlaceHolder, which I'll use to insert one of the user controls depending, which version is required.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphScripts" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

and finally in the master's page codebehind I'm adding the needed user control to the placeholder:

```
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["theme"] != null)
                {
                    switch (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["theme"].Value)
                    {
                        case "Desktop":
                            cphScripts.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl/ScriptManagerDesktop.ascx"));
                            break;
                        case "Mobile":
                            cphScripts.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl/ScriptManagerMobile.ascx"));
                            break;
                        default:
                            cphScripts.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl/ScriptManagerDesktop.ascx"));
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

And voila I've got your `ScriptManager` switcher ready to go.

Hope this will help someone.